# Python3 pip installing globally when in a virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-3.3, virtualenvwrapper

Attempting to finally make the jump to Python 3, but am running into some issues with virtualenvwrapper. I start out by creating the virtual environment like so:

`mkvirtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 projectname`

which yields:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3'
New python executable in projectname/bin/python3.3
Also creating executable in projectname/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
```

So far, so good. I check the python console to make sure that the environment is looking at the correct interpreter and all that and it is. Here's where sadness happens (while the virtualenv is active):

`pip install flask` claims to be successful, but alas:

```
Python 3.3.3 (default, Jan  2 2014, 13:26:32) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import flask
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'flask'
```

Here's the issue:

```
$ pip show flask
---
Name: Flask
Version: 0.10.1
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages
Requires: Werkzeug, Jinja2, itsdangerous
```

Unless I'm completely misunderstanding virtualenv/wrapper and their respective magics (which I very well could be), it seems like pip install is installing Flask globally rather than to the site-packages within my virtualenv, and thus the virtualenv is ignoring it.

Any clues what's going on here/how to fix? Am I wrong in assuming that virtualenvwrapper is ready for primetime with python3? Pretty solutions where I don't have to mangle my .bashrc or manually set environment variables are preferable. I'm hoping there's a way to do this through the api's provided by virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper.

Thanks!

Comment: What versions of `pip` and `virtualenv`? (Or are you using `venv` instead of `virtualenv`?) I remember some problem with pip 1.4 and recent virtualenv versions (even though those versions came with 1.4) that was solved by upgrading to pip 1.5, but I can't remember if this was the problem…

Comment: the pip that's in use once i've activated the virtualenv is: pip 1.5 from /usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages (python 3.3). 

i use virtualenvwrapper to abstract away the virtualenv stuff, but when i type `virtualenv --version` i get 1.11

Comment: OK, so it's using your system `pip` rather than your virtualenv's `pip`, which I'd expect to cause exactly this problem. Does `which pip` show /usr/local/bin/pip, or is it the correct path (the one inside your env)?

Comment: Or, alternatively, you can use your system `pip` as long as you pass -E, or `export PIP_RESPECT_VIRTUALENV=true`. You may also need to `export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=$WORKON_HOME`.

Comment: `which pip` is saying "~/.virtualenvs/spelling/bin/pip." that seems right. the system pip appears to be version 1.3 though... maybe the outdated version is doing something strange as it's setting up the virtualenv?

Comment: That's definitely possible. Try upgrading the system `pip` to the 1.5 and then start a new shell and activate the venv and see if it works.

Comment: system pip is now up to date, but sadly no dice. modules still seem to be installing to /usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages

Comment: Sadly, the only system I've got `virtualenvwrapper` set up on is an older Python 3.2/pip 1.3, and it's using python.org Python instead of Homebrew. If I get a chance, I'll set it up on my other machine and see if I can repro/debug your problem. But hopefully someone else will come along and help you before then.

Comment: SO has notified me that i'm now abusing the comments sections with the length of this thread, but ONE MORE piece of interesting information: despite the fact that `which pip` says it's using one installed in the virtualenv, when i do `pip --version` it says "pip 1.5 from /usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages," so i think it is indeed using the system pip-3.3 despite the deceptive output of `which pip.` is there a simple fix to make it use a local pip instead if this is the case?

Comment: If you look at the `pip` program (`cat $(which pip)`), you'll see that (a) it's a Python script, so if the #! line is wrong you will run the wrong interpreter, and (b) it's a trivial script that just imports and runs some code from an installed module, so if it's importing from the wrong `sys.path` you'll get the wrong `pip` code. I don't know which of those two is going wrong for you, or why, or how to fix it, but that may help you figure out where to dig in next.

Comment: Aha! The problem is indeed with the #! line (#!/usr/local/bin/python3). Once I change it to point to the proper python interpreter everything magically works. The `pip --version` seems to imply that it copies the pip-3.3 file from "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages." maybe it copies it over literally without changing the interpreter line? I wonder if this is a bug in pip-1.5-py3.3 or virtualenv or something...

Comment: I'll have to set things up myself before I can do more than guess, but… I'll bet it's something like this: virtualenv expects your `pip` to use something like `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, which will work just fine when you activate the virtualenv. If you install a python.org binary of Python 3.3, then install `pip` via `get-pip.py`, you end up with that, and everything works fine. But if you install Python 3.3 via Homebrew (with its slightly customized config and pre-installed `pip`), you end up with a different #!. Not really a bug in either virtualenv or Homebrew's package, but together…

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with pip installing packages globally instead of in the activated virtualenv too. Have a look at [pip installing in global site-packages instead of virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952797/pip-installing-in-global-site-packages-instead-of-virtualenv) for the question (and the answer).

Basically, the solution consisted of modifying the shebang of the pip scripts within the virtualenv as they pointed to the wrong python installation (global instead of in the virtualenv). Just change the shebang to point to the correct location and you're set.

*Note: credit should go to Chase Ries who came up with the solution.*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  It appears to be resolved as of Virtualenv 1.11.4.