# pip installing in global site-packages instead of virtualenv

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, pip

Using `pip3` to install a package in a `virtualenv` causes the package to be installed in the global site-packages folder instead of the one in the virtualenv folder. Here's how I set up Python3 and virtualenv on OS X Mavericks (10.9.1):

I installed Python3 using Homebrew:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
brew install python3 --with-brewed-openssl
```

Changed the `$PATH` variable in `.bash_profile`; added the following line:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Running `which python3` returns `/usr/local/bin/python3` (after restarting the shell).

*Note: `which python3` still returns /`usr/bin/python` though.*

Installed `virtualenv` using `pip3`:

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```

Next, create a new `virtualenv` and activate it:

```
virtualenv testpy3 -p python3
cd testpy3
source bin/activate
```

*Note: if I don't specify -p python3, pip will be missing from the bin folder in the virtualenv.*

Running `which pip` and `which pip3` both return the virtualenv folder:

```
/Users/kristof/VirtualEnvs/testpy3/bin/pip3
```

Now, when I try to install e.g. Markdown using pip in the activated virtualenv, pip will install in the global site-packages folder instead of the site-packages folder of the virtualenv.

```
pip install markdown
```

Running `pip list` returns:

```
Markdown (2.3.1)
pip (1.4.1)
setuptools (2.0.1)
virtualenv (1.11)
```

Contents of `/Users/kristof/VirtualEnvs/testpy3/lib/python3.3/site-packages`:

```
__pycache__/
_markerlib/
easy_install.py
pip/
pip-1.5.dist-info/
pkg_resources.py
setuptools/
setuptools-2.0.2.dist-info/
```

Contents of `/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages`:

```
Markdown-2.3.1-py3.3.egg-info/
__pycache__/
easy-install.pth
markdown/
pip-1.4.1-py3.3.egg/
setuptools-2.0.1-py3.3.egg
setuptools.pth
virtualenv-1.11-py3.3.egg-info/
virtualenv.py
virtualenv_support/
```

As you can see, the **global** site-packages folder contains Markdown, the virtualenv folder doesn't.

Note: I had Python2 and Python3 installed before on a different VM (followed [these](http://hackercodex.com/guide/python-development-environment-on-mac-osx/) instructions) and had the same issue with Python3; installing packages in a Python2 based virtualenv worked flawlessly though.

Any tips, hints, … would be very much appreciated.

Comment: pip doesn't install a package if it is already available. You should see "Requirement already satisfied" in its output. Try to install  a package that you do not have yet. btw, pip3 might use non-brew python3 (how do you install `pip3`?). It might not be bad by itself but you should be aware if it is.

Comment: I didn't have Markdown installed before. The global package list was empty. It doesn't matter what package I try, I can reproduce this behaviour every time.

Comment: Regarding pip3: this was installed by homebrew, together with Python3.

Comment: For me this also helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695278/python-packages-not-installing-in-virtualenv-using-pip#14695504 Just for FYI to others

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Funny you brought this up, I just had the exact same problem. I solved it eventually, but I'm still unsure as to what caused it.

Try checking your `bin/pip` and `bin/activate` scripts. In `bin/pip`, look at the shebang. Is it correct? If not, correct it. Then on line ~`42` in your `bin/activate`, check to see if your virtualenv path is right. It'll look something like this

```
VIRTUAL_ENV="/Users/me/path/to/virtual/environment"
```

If it's wrong, correct it, `deactivate`, then `. bin/activate`, and if our mutual problem had the same cause, it should work. If it still doesn't, you're on the right track, anyway. I went through the same problem solving routine as you did, `which pip`ing over and over, following the stack trace, etc.

Make absolutely sure that

```
/Users/kristof/VirtualEnvs/testpy3/bin/pip3
```

is what you want, and not referring to another similarly-named test project (I had that problem, and have no idea how it started. My suspicion is running multiple virtualenvs at the same time).

If none of this works, a temporary solution may be to, as Joe Holloway said,

> Just run the virtualenv's pip with its full path (i.e. don't rely on searching the executable path) and you don't even need to activate the environment. It will do the right thing.

Perhaps not ideal, but it ought to work in a pinch.

Link to my original question:

[VirtualEnv/Pip trying to install packages globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942982/virtualenv-pip-trying-to-install-packages-globally)

Comment: Thanks Chase. I came by your question before posting mine, but it seems I skipped the very last line which mentioned the shebang. And indeed, it was set to `#!/usr/local/bin/python3.3` instead of `#!/Users/kristof/VirtualEnvs/testpy3/bin/python3.3`. I changed it, activated the virtualenv and installed the Markdown package. Pip now installs in the virtualenv site-packages folder instead of the global one.

Comment: I ran into this too, thanks so much for the answer. I noticed the shebangs and then immediately afterward found this question, confirming my suspicions. Does anyone know why the shebang was wrong? It would be nice to find a permanent fix so we don't have to check it every time we make a new virtual environment.

Comment: I had the same problem. My `activate` script was fine, but **beware**, _all_ the `pip*` scripts and `easy_install*` scripts have the wrong shebang. They all have to be fixed manually. I was unable to fix them via reinstalling pip or anything like that. Also, a clarification to Joe Holloway's workaround: the problem is not with the shell searching for pip, it's the fact that pip explicitly specifies the _wrong_ python. Therefore you would need to specify the python yourself, like so: `$ ~/.virtualenvs/venv/bin/python ~/.virtualenvs/venv/bin/pip --version`

Comment: I met this problem after a `--relocatable` my env, and the line 42 is wrong, Looks like the `--relocatable` did not do it job right.

Comment: This happened to me when I renamed an intermediate directory, so I had to edit activate and pip scripts in '/bin'

Comment: For me (Mac OS Sierra, python 3.5 installed by brew) I fixed this using the first line of your advice: edit the pip in the virtualenv. The shebang was hardcoded, instead it should be:

#!/usr/bin/env python

Comment: I had moved my virtual environment to different path. This caused the all packages to be installed globally. this helped me thanks!

Comment: This fixed it for me. My issue was that I changed the folder name so the path in activate was no longer correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem, I solved it by removing venv directory and recreating it!

```
deactivate (if venv is activated first deactivate it)
rm -rf venv
virtualenv -p python3 venv
. ENV/bin/activate
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Now everything works like a charm.

**Edit**: Here's the above code modified for Python3's venv:

```
deactivate # (if venv is activated first deactivate it)
rm -rf venv # Delete the old venv directory
python3 -m venv venv # Recreate a new, empty venv
. venv/bin/activate # Activate it
pip3 install -r requirements.txt # Install the dependencies
```

Comment: I was using `pip3` while virtualenv, by default, used python2 thus using `pip` instead of `pip3`. I checked the `bin` to find no `pip3`. Using `virtualenv -p python3 venv` solved the problem.

Comment: This solved my problem. Pycharm's automatic virtualenv creation was not working properly. Manual installation did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: For me, it helped removing the venv and installing it again. virtualenv is deprecated from python3.6 on, use for example  'python3.6 -m venv'` instead.

Comment: I'm on windows and I was having trouble following the other answers. Thank you for this.

Comment: It seems to me that the key is to activate the virtual env BEFORE calling pip install. For me the activation was missing.

Answer (score 22):

For me this was not a pip or virtualenv problem. It was a python problem. I had set my $PYTHONPATH manually in ~/.bash_profile (or ~/.bashrc) after following some tutorial online. This manually set $PYTHONPATH was available in the virtualenv as it probably should be allowed.

Additionally `add2virtualenv` was not adding my project path to my $PYTHONPATH for some reason within the virtualenv.

Just some forking paths for those who might still be stuck! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! For me this was caused by a ros setup script: `source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash`

Comment: Thanks for the idea! For some reason I cannot remember, I had edited my `.bashrc` file in a previous laptop, and when migrating to a new one, the old `.bashrc` file was messing up my new setup. The line that was bringing me the headaches was `alias pip='/usr/bin/pip'`.

Answer (score 10):

The first thing to check is which location pip is resolving to:

```
which pip
```

if you are in a virtualenv you would expect this to give you something like:

> /path/to/virtualenv/.name_of_virtualenv/bin/pip

However it may be the case that it's resolving to your system pip for some reason. For example you may see this from within your virtualenv (this is bad):

> /usr/local/bin/pip
>   (or anything that isn't in your virtualenv path).

To solve this check your pipconfig in:

```
~/.pipconf
~/.conf/pip
/etc/pip.conf
```

and make sure that there is nothing that is coercing your Python path or your pip path (this fixed it for me).

Then try starting a new terminal and rebuild your virtualenv (delete then create it again)

Comment: Also check `/etc/pip.conf`! I had a similar issue and after a lot of debugging figured someone misconfigured the system I was working on by messing around with this file.

Comment: I am using arch Linux. I think the /etc/pip.conf is set up by the OS.

Comment: I had a terminal session defined alias that overriden pip, for some reasons `which pip` was still giving me the correct path!

Comment: How to solve this in windows?
I am getting same path in both virtual environment and global:
/c/Users/UserName/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/pip

Comment: @AakashSolanki just delete the venv folder and recreate it. Then reinstall the packages within the new venv.

Answer (score 8):

Go to bin directory in your virtual environment and write like this:

```
./pip3 install <package-name>
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue on macos with python 2 and 3 installed.

Also, I had aliases to point to python3 and pip3 in my `.bash_profile`.

```
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3
alias pip=/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

Removing aliases and recreating virtual env using `python3 -m venv venv` fixed the issue.

Comment: macos python installation is needlessly painful imho

Comment: I was pulling my hair out, and this is what finally fixed things for me: "which pip" revealed the problem, "unalias pip" fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem too.  Calling `pip install <package_name>` from the `/bin` directory within my Python 3.3 virtual environment on my Mavericks Mac caused the Python package to be installed in the Python 2.7 global site packages directory.  This was despite the fact that my $PATH started with the directory containing `pip`.  Weird. This doesn't happen on CentOS.  For me, the solution was calling `pip3` instead of `pip`.  When I had installed **pip** within the virtual environment via **ez_setup**, three "pip" executables had been installed in the `/bin` directory - `pip`, `pip3`, and `pip3.3`. Curiously, all three files were exactly the same.  Calling `pip3 install <package_name>` caused the Python package to be installed correctly into the local site-packages directory.  Calling `pip` with the full pathname into the virtual environment also worked correctly.  I'd be interested to know why my Mac isn't using $PATH the way I would expect it to.

Answer (score 5):

I hit into the same issue while installing a python package from within a virtualenv.
The root cause in my case was different.
From within the virtualenv, I was (out of habit on Ubuntu), doing:

```
sudo easy_install -Z <package>
```

This caused the bin/pip shebang to be ignored and it used the root's non virtualenv python to install it in the global site-packages.
Since we have a virtual environment, we should install the package without "sudo"

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled upon the same problem running Manjaro. I created the virtual environment using `python3 -m ven venv` and then activated using `source venv/bin/actiave`. `which python` and `which pip` both pointed towards the correct binaries in the virtualenv, however I was not able to install to the virtualenv, even when using the full path of the binaries. Turned out that when I uninstalled the python-pip package with `sudo pacman -R python-pip python-reportlab` (had to include reportlab to satisfy dependencies) everything started to work as expected. Not sure why, but this is probably due to a double install where the system package is taking precedence.

Comment: I also had this problem on Manjaro, and resolved it the same way. After resolving I reinstalled `python-pip` via pamac and the virtualenv pip continued to function correctly. Not sure exactly what is going on, but I agree with your assessment of a double install issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem after updating to `pip==8.0.0`. Had to resort to debugging pip to trace out the bad path.

As it turns out my profile directory had a distutils configuration file with some empty path values. This was causing all packages to be installed to the same root directory instead of the appropriate virtual environment (in my case `/lib/site-packages`).

I'm unsure how the config file got there or how it had empty values but it started after updating pip.

In case anyone else stumbles upon this same problem, simply deleting the file `~/.pydistutils.cfg` (or removing the empty config path) fixed the problem in my environment because pip went back to the default distributed configuration.

Comment: This my issue as well. My file looked like this, no idea how it got there:
`[install]\nprefix=`

Answer (score 3):

Here are some practices that could avoid headaches when using **Virtual Environments:**

- Create a folder for your projects.
- Create your **Virtualenv** projects inside of this folder.
- After activating the environment of your project, never use "**sudo** *pip install package*".
- After finishing your work, always "**deactivate**" your environment.
- Avoid renaming your project folder.

---

For a better representation of this practices, here is a simulation:

#### creating a folder for your projects/environments

```
$ mkdir venv
```

#### creating environment

```
$ cd venv/ 

$ virtualenv google_drive
New python executable in google_drive/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
```

#### activating environment

```
$ source google_drive/bin/activate
```

#### installing packages

```
(google_drive) $ pip install PyDrive
Downloading/unpacking PyDrive
Downloading PyDrive-1.3.1-py2-none-any.whl
...
...
...    
Successfully installed PyDrive PyYAML google-api-python-client oauth2client six uritemplate httplib2 pyasn1 rsa pyasn1-modules
Cleaning up...
```

#### package available inside the environment

```
(google_drive) $ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import pydrive.auth
>>>  
>>> gdrive = pydrive.auth.GoogleAuth()
>>>
```

#### deactivate environment

```
(google_drive) $ deactivate 

$
```

#### package NOT AVAILABLE outside the environment

```
(google_drive) $ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:32:10) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import pydrive.auth
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pydrive.auth
>>>
```

---

#### Notes:

#### Why not sudo?

> Virtualenv creates a whole new environment for you, defining $PATH and some other variables and settings. When you use **sudo pip install package**, you are running Virtualenv as **root**, escaping the whole environment which was created, and then, installing  the package on global site-packages, **and not inside the project folder** where you have a Virtual Environment, although you have activated the environment.

#### If you rename the folder of your project (as mentioned in the accepted answer)...

> ...you'll have to adjust some variables from some files inside the **bin** directory of your project.
>
> For example:
>
> bin/pip, line 1 (She Bang)
>
> bin/activate, line 42 (VIRTUAL_ENV)

Comment: Yes sudo was my problem
But since I did not have required permission because i was creating in apache directory
hence i used sudo -s to gain root access after that enabling venv and installing using pip

Answer (score 3):

This problem occurs when create a virtualenv instance and then change the parent folder name.

Comment: this was the cause in my case. I moved .venv folder to upper directory and this issue started.I fixed it by recreating the .venv.  Ty captain

Answer (score 1):

Came across the same issue today. I simply reinstalled pip globally with `sudo easy_install pip` (OSX/ Max), then created my virtualenv again with `sudo virtualenv nameOfVEnv`. Then after activating the new virtualenv the `pip` command worked as expected.

I don't think I used `sudo` on the first virtualenv creation and that may have been the reason for not having access to `pip` from within the virtualenv, I was able to get access to `pip2` before this fix though which was odd.

Comment: I got this because I moved the directory to another path and it needed `virtualenv` to be run again

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. It turned out there was a space in one of my folder names that caused the problem. I removed the space, deleted and reinstantiated using venv, and all was well.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above solutions worked for me.

My venv was active. 
`pip -V` and `which pip` gave me the correct virtualenv path, but when I `pip install`-ed packages with activated venv, my `pip freeze` stayed empty.

All the environment variables were correct too.

Finally, I just changed pip and removed virtualenv:

```
easy_install pip==7.0.2

pip install pip==10

sudo pip uninstall virtualenv
```

Reinstall venv:

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

Create venv:

```
python -m virtualenv venv_name_here
```

And all packages installed correctly into my venv again.

Answer (score 1):

After creating virtual environment, try to use pip located in **yourVirtualEnvName\Scripts**

It should install a package inside **Lib\site-packages** in your virtual environment

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on Windows. It was caused by renaming folder structures in my project within a virtualenv folder name. The paths in files didn't change but stayed as they were when virtual env was created. As Chase Ries mentioned I've changed the paths to VIRTUAL_ENV and python.exe in files

1. **./venv/Scripts/activate.bat**, `set "VIRTUAL_ENV=path_to_venv\venv"` 11 line in file
2. **./venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1**,  `$env:VIRTUAL_ENV="path_to_venv\venv"` 30 line in file
3. **./venv/Scripts/pip.exe**, `#!d:\path_to_env\venv\scripts\python.exe` this line is at the end of a file, in my case moved to the right in 667 line, I am working on disc d so at the begining of the path is the letter of it
4. **./venv/Scripts/pip3.7.exe**, `#!d:\path_to_env\venv\scripts\python.exe` this line is at the end of a file, in my case moved to the right in 667 line
5. **./venv/Scripts/pip3.exe**, `#!d:\path_to_env\venv\scripts\python.exe` this line is at the end of a file, in my case moved to the right in 667 line

Comment: How did you edit a .exe file?

Comment: I opened it with Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Pip installing only globally.
It means there is a problem in pip's configuration.

First, find pip config files:

```
python -m pip config debug
```

It will list all pip config files. If there 'false' (no file), create it (or add line respect - virtualenv = true):

```
   [global]
   default-timeout = 60
   respect-virtualenv = true
   download-cache = /tmp
   log-file = /tmp/pip-log.txt
```

Comment: You just ended a 5 hours struggle. it worked, thx!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. Calling `sudo pip install` caused Python packages to be installed in the global site-packages diretory and calling `pip install` just worked fine.
So no use **sudo** in virtualenv.

Comment: Or if you use sudo, you also have to activate the virtual environment. `sudo su` followed by `<venv>/bin/activate` followed by `pip install`.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem. Python3.5 and pip 8.0.2 installed from Linux `rpm`'s.

I did not find a primary cause and cannot give a proper answer. It looks like there are multiple possible causes.

However, I hope I can help with sharing my observation and a workaround.

1. `pyvenv` with `--system-site-packages`

   - `./bin` does not contain `pip`, `pip` is available from system site packages
   - packages are installed globally (**BUG?**)
2. `pyvenv` without `--system-site-packages`

   - `pip` gets installed into `./bin`, but it's a different version (from `ensurepip`)
   - packages are installed within the virtual environment (**OK**)

Obvious workaround for `pyvenv` with `--system-site-packages`:

- create it without the `--system-site-packages` option
- change `include-system-site-packages = false` to `true` in `pyvenv.cfg` file

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth checking that you didn't modify somehow the path to your virtualenv.

In that case the first line in `bin/pip` (and the rest of the executables) would have an incorrect path.

You can either edit these files and fix the path or remove and install again the virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

**For Python 3ers**

Try updating. I had this exact same problem and tried Chases' answer, however no success. The quickest way to refactor this is to update your Python Minor / Patch version if possible. I noticed that I was running 3.5.1 and updated to 3.5.2. Pyvenv once again works.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I created the virtualenv in the wrong location. I then thought I could move the dir to another location without it mattering. It mattered.

```
mkdir ~/projects
virtualenv myenv
cd myenv
git clone [my repository]
```

Oh crap, I forgot to cd into `projects` before creating the virtualenv and cloning the rep. Oh well, I'm too lazy to destroy and recreate. I'll just move the dir with no issues.

```
cd ~
mv myenv projects
cd projects/myenv/myrepo
pip install -r requirements
```

Nope, wants more permissions, what the?
I thought it was strange but SUDO AWAY! It then installed the packages into a global location.

The lesson I learned was, just delete the virtualenv dir. Don't move it.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue after installing Divio: it had changed my PATH or environment in some way, as it launches a terminal.

The solution in this case was just to do `source ~/.bash_profile` which should already be setup to get you back to your original pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv state.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow a setup.cfg file with a prefix="" in the project folder

running pip install on the virtualenv outside the project folder worked so from the inside it was telling pip to use an empty prefix  which defaults to "/"

removing the file fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and after trying all the above solution I just removed everything and started afresh.

In my own case i used `sudo` in creating one of the folders in which the virtual environment existed, and sudo give the priviledges to root

I was very pissed! But it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I have to use 'sudo' for installing packages through pip on my ubuntu system for some reason. This is causing the packages to be installed in global site-packages. Putting this here for anyone who might face this issue in future.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the problem from the title, and I solved it. Pip started to install in the venv site-packages after I cleaned my PATH: it had a path to my local ~/bin directory at the very beginning.

So, my advice: thoroughly check your environment variables for "garbage" or any non-standard things. Unfortunately, virtualenv can be sensitive to those.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Lot of good discussion above, but virtualenv examples were used. Since 'conda' is now the recommended  tool to manage virtualenv, I have summarized the steps in running pip in conda env as follow.

I'll use py36r as the name of the env, and /opt/conda/envs is the prefix to the envs):

```
$ source /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh # skip if already done 
$ conda activate py36r
$ pip  install pkg_xyz
$ pip  list | grep pkg_xyz
```

Note that the pip executed should be in `/opt/conda/envs/py36r/bin/pip` (not `/opt/conda/bin/pip`).

Alternatively, you can simply run the following without conda activate

```
$ /opt/conda/envs/py36r/bin/pip
```

Also, if you install using conda, you can install without activate:

```
$ conda install -n py36r pkg_abc ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is run Command virtualenv with parameter “—no-site-packages”.

Long answer with explanation :-

So after running here and there, and going through lot of threads i found my self the problem. Above answers have given the idea but I would like to go again over everything though.

- The problem is even if you’re activating the environment it’s referring to the system environment because of the way we have crated the virtualenv.
- when we run the command *virtualenv env -p python3* 
  it will install the virtualenv but it will not create no-global—site-packages.txt.
- Because of that when you activate the environment by source activate command there this file called site.py (name can be different, i just forgot ) which runs and checks if this file is not present it will not add your env path to sys.path and use systems python.
- to fix this issue just run virtualenv with extra parameter —no-site-packages it will create that file and when you activate the environment it will add your custom environment path in your PATH variable making it accessible.

Answer (score 0):

WINDOWS

For me solution was not to use
`mkvirtualenv`, but:

`python -m venv path/to/your/virtualenv`

workon works correctly.

while in virtualenv: `pip -V` shows virtualenv's path to pip

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem, it troubled me for a long time, until I solved it according to @Chase Ries method.

The key to solving the problem is：

> Try checking your `bin/pip` and `bin/activate` scripts. In `bin/pip`, look at the shebang. Is it correct? If not, correct it. Then on line ~`42` in your `bin/activate`, check to see if your virtualenv path is right. It'll look something like this
>
> ```py
> VIRTUAL_ENV="/Users/me/path/to/virtual/environment"
> ```
>
> If it's wrong, correct it, `deactivate`, then `. bin/activate`, and if our mutual problem had the same cause, it should work.

Below, I will explain this process in detail in the `Ubuntu` environment, the same is true for `Windows` and `MacOS`.

The meaning of this sentence is that **we need to check whether the first line `#!/path/python` of the `bin/pip` file in the virtual environment is correct.**

As originally shown in my file:

`#!/home/banni/dai/.venv/bin/python3`

Run `pip` in terminal（**absolute path**）：

`/home/banni/dai/.venv/bin/pip`

Will find an error：

`bash: ./pip: /home/banni/dai/.venv/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Now I am confused why I can't find this `python3`, because `python3` exists in the folder `.venv/bin` where the virtual environment is located.

I check the absolute path of the folder `.venv/bin`. After executing the `pwd` command, it displays:

`/home/banni/Research/dai/.venv/bin`

Carefully observe that the path of the `.venv` folder has changed. Change the first line of the `/bin/pip` file to

`#!/home/banni/Research/dai/.venv/bin/python3`

In the same way, check and modify the `bin/activate` file.

I changed `VIRTUAL_ENV="/home/banni/dai/.venv"` to `VIRTUAL_ENV="/home/banni/Research/dai/.venv"`

At this point, after activating the virtual environment, the `pip` command can be executed normally.

So, for me, the reason for this problem is that **the path of the folder where the virtual environment is located has changed** (a secret problem that was left when the folders were organized before).

However, due to the change in the location of the folder where the virtual environment is located, there may be many path errors, so the easiest way is to restore the folder where the virtual environment is located to the original location.

Answer (score 0):

1. Activate virtual env
2. Use `where pip` to find out pip location, if in base env, probably 'pip' is not
   installed
3. Type

> conda install pip

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I checked all the answers here but none of them worked for me. Especially checked Chase Ries's answer and directories were correct in pip.exe and activate.bat ( for Windows )

I solved the issue by copying the pip.ini ( for Windows, I think it's something else for other OS) which was located in C:\Users\oguno\AppData\Roaming\pip to C:\Users\oguno\Desktop\iec61850\myenv3 where my venv located and change the the target as C:\Users\oguno\Desktop\iec61850\myenv3\Lib\site-packages which shows the site-packages in my virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

For those who checked the python and pip has correct virtualenv path, another possible problem lies in pip configuration

In my case, i added --prefix in config file to install packages in different paths. This is picked up by virtualenv pip which resulted in installing in the same place as global pip.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and fixed it by removing spaces in my directories leading to venv path.

Answer (score 0):

It's amazing how many solutions there are to this intricate problem, and especially amazing (for me) how none of them were what I needed to resolve my issue. In my case, the `pip.ini` file had specified a target value and **removing the target** resolved the problem.

*broken pip.ini*

```
[global]
index-url = work-artifactory-cloud-api-key
trusted-host = work-artifactory-cloud
proxy = http://work-artifactory-cloud.com:2000/
target = ~/site-packages
```

*fixed pip.ini*

```
[global]
index-url = work-artifactory-cloud-api-key
trusted-host = work-artifactory-cloud
proxy = http://work-artifactory-cloud.com:2000/
```

you may not need "index-url", "trusted-host" and "proxy" if you're using a personal machine. I'm not great at python, and I'm much worse at SysAdmin, but thankfully I stumbled across the right GitHub Issue that helped debug this issue for me: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11154

You can find where your `pip.ini` file is by running `pip config debug` and you can see what's inside this `pip.ini` by running `pip config list`

Answer (score -1):

It happened to me when I installed virtualenv with `--python=python3.6` flag but afterwards tried to use `pip2 install`.
Creating virtualenv with flag of the version that you'll use solves permission problems. To check, try `which pip` or `which pip2` or `which pip3` (depends on your choice). If any `pip` you use shows path not to `venv` here is your problem.