# Pip Install not installing into correct directory?

Tags: python, bash, installation, pip

I can't seem to use sudo pip install correctly so that it installs into the following directory:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

so that I can then import the module using python

I've run

```
sudo pip install scikit-learn --upgrade
```

Result

```
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

However, it's not in the correct directory

How do I get sudo pip install to install into correct directory?

In addition, I've tried

sudo pip install Scrappy

I get the following message

```
new-host-2:site-packages Chris$ sudo pip install Scrapy
Password:
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Scrapy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Twisted>=10.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): w3lib>=1.8.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): queuelib in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lxml in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyOpenSSL in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cssselect>=0.9 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.5.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): zope.interface>=3.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Twisted>=10.0.0->Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cryptography>=0.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pyOpenSSL->Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from zope.interface>=3.6.0->Twisted>=10.0.0->Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cffi>=0.8 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=0.2.1->pyOpenSSL->Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cffi>=0.8->cryptography>=0.2.1->pyOpenSSL->Scrapy)
```

Both these instances demonstrate that it's been installed but not correctly. For example, when I run the following import in python:

```
import scrapy
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-51c73a18167b> in <module>()
----> 1 import scrapy

ImportError: No module named scrapy
```

I've tried the following:

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Comment: You need to run pip installed for the python installation you want.
i.e.: you probably have more than 1 python installed... check if you are running the python installed as a Framework or other one, and use pip from the one you want, it should be in the "bin" directory of the installation you want.

Comment: how do you check if you are running python as a framework?

Comment: "type python" gives you the location you are running python from.

Then type "ls -l <python with full path>" to check if it's a link to another location.
You probably want to run the one in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

Comment: Thanks - you are absolutely right as I get "/usr/local/bin/python" from "type python." How would I delete that one or at least just get sudo pip install to always go into "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/"? In other words, how do I run pip installed for the python installation I want?

Comment: You can create a link to the python you want.

i.e: sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

But, I would recommend you run pip from the Framework, it's probably in the path /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip

So type /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip install <the lib>

Comment: I'm at a loss of why I can't get this to work even with sudo ln -s. I really want the ability to properly install packages into the correct directory so I'm starting a bounty on this.

Comment: I guess there are more than 2 pip in your OS X, the one with prefix "/usr/local/lib" might be installed using "brew". If so, you should use the corresponding "python" instead of build-in python("/usr/bin/python") , it should be located in "/usr/local/bin/python".

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915471/install-a-python-package-into-a-different-directory-using-pip

Comment: Had a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/35005473/39013

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From the comments to the original question, it seems that you have multiple versions of python installed and that pip just goes to the wrong version.

First, to know which version of python you're using, just type `which python`. You should either see:

```
which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

if you're going to the right version of python, or:

```
which python
/usr/bin/python
```

If you're going to the 'wrong' version. To make pip go to the right version, you first have to change the path:

```
 export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python:${PATH}
```

typing 'which python' would now get you to the right result. Next, install pip (if it's not already installed for this installation of python). Finally, use it. you should be fine now.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I'm having an issue with your solution though. I've tried to type in: export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python:{PATH}. This doesnt work. I've tried to type in export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python:{/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/}, which doesnt work. I've also tried export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ .

Comment: Hi Chris. First - I had a type in my original response - I missed a '$' sign in `export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python:${PATH}`. Second - when you say it doesn't work - what do you mean by that? Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Note that it's easier to just run "python -m pip", to be sure that you're using the correct version of Python with pip.

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me on Windows. The cause being multiple python installations

1. update path with correct python
2. uninstall pip using `python -m pip uninstall pip setuptools`
3. restart windows *didn't work until a restart*

Answer (score 3):

[Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) is your friend

Even if you want to add a package to your primary install, it's still best to do it in a virtual environment first, to ensure compatibility with your other packages. However, if you get familiar with virtualenv, you'll probably find there's really no reason to install anything in your base install.

Answer (score 2):

### 1 - Something that might work

The `pip` executable is actually a Python script.

By default it contains (on Linux):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'pip==1.5.6','console_scripts','pip'
__requires__ = 'pip==1.5.6'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
    )
```

So if you got the same in MacOS, `pip` would always use `/usr/bin/python`.

But this is a default. You can still provide the version of python you want either by editing the file or by using python explicitly.

If `which python` returns `/usr/bin/python` then something went wrong when you installed your own version. If it is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`, you can directly call:

```
sudo python `which pip` install scikit-learn --upgrade
```

However, chances are high that it won't work. The reason is that `sudo` is resetting all your environment variables. To make it work, the easiest would be to use:

```
sudo -E pip install scikit-learn --upgrade
```

or

```
sudo -E python `which pip` install scikit-learn --upgrade
```

depending on your setup.

### 2 - What you should do

`pip` was not thought of as something that `root` should execute. The actual best way to use it is to install a local, non-root, python version. You just have to make sure that you use it by default by setting up the correct environment variables (such as `PATH` on Linux) and then install `pip` without `sudo` using that python version.

An even better way would be to setup `virtualenv`s from your root install.

This way, you can install/update whatever you want without root privileges and never bother again about why `sudo pip` is not working. You would also avoid to provide root privileges to whatever is on Pypi and that would warrant that you don't mix system libs with your own.

Comment: `which python` returns for me: `/opt/local/bin/python` (installed using `macports`) and this is the version I want to use. `which pip` returns `/usr/local/bin/pip`, that is associated with the default `python`. How can I install `virtualenv` using the macports-python given that I should use `pip` as per the manual (http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)?

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with the guys, it's better to use **virtualenv** so you can set a custom environment for every project. It ideal for maintenance because it's like a different world for every project and every update of an application you make won't interfere with other projects.

[Here you can find a nutshell of virtualenv](http://beni7ez.com/?p=58) related to installation and first steps.

Comment: Well, the post was from two years ago. This link is useful as well http://www.simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

1. download pip at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip (tar)
2. unzip tar file
3. cd to the file’s directory
4. sudo python2.7 setup.py install

Answer (score 1):

You could just change the shebang line. I do this all the time on new systems.

If you want `pip` to install to a current version of Python installed just update the shebang line to the correct version of pythons path.

For example, to change pip (not pip3) to install to Python 3:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

To:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Any module you install using `pip` should install to Python not Python.

Or you could just change the path.

Comment: This one worked perfectly for me.
There are multiple pythons and multiple python3.
Even after installing a package via pip or pip3, it always showed the package missing.

I changed the first line of `pip` command to the same python my script refers to and installed package again.

All sorted now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this and it worked for me,

```
curl -O  https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c0/4d/d2cd1171f93245131686b67d905f38cab53bf0edc3fd1a06b9c667c9d046/boto3-1.14.29.tar.gz

tar -zxvf boto3-1.14.29.tar.gz

cd boto3-1.14.29/
```

Replace X with your required python interpreter, for mine it was python3

```
sudo pythonX setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows it happened to me when I upgraded the pip version from `23.0.1` to `23.2.1`. This was in Python `3.10.11`.

To fix it I just downgraded to pip back to `23.0.1`

`python -m pip install pip==23.0.1`

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you pip version matches your python version.

to get your python version use:

python -V

then install the correct pip.  You might already have intall in that case try to use:

pip-2.5 install ...

pip-2.7 install ...

or for those of you using macports make sure your version match using.

port select --list pip

then change to the same python version you are using.

sudo port select --set pip pip27

Hope this helps. It work on my end.

Answer (score -3):

You Should uninstall the existed python,then download new version.