# ImportError: No module named matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Matplotlib was working fine few months back. But now I keep getting the error:

```
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

I again installed matplotlib using pip. It didn't work. I used easyinstall. Still not working.

pip installation gives

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): matplotlib in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.6 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.4.2-py2.7.egg (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz-2015.7-py2.7.egg (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cycler in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cycler-0.9.0-py2.7.egg (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyparsing!=2.0.0,!=2.0.4,>=1.5.6 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyparsing-2.0.6-py2.7.egg (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg (from python-dateutil->matplotlib)
```

Then I used

```
sudo -E pip install matplotlib --upgrade
```

after which i got

```
The directory '/Users/ruskin/Library/Logs/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the debug log has been disabled.        Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/ruskin/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled.   Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
You are using pip version 6.1.1, however version 7.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
The directory '/Users/ruskin/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

It continued upgrading matplotlib but in the end i got

```
Requirement already up-to-date: python-dateutil in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.4.2-py2.7.egg (from matplotlib)
Requirement already up-to-date: pytz in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz-2015.7-py2.7.egg (from matplotlib)
Requirement already up-to-date: cycler in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cycler-0.9.0-py2.7.egg (from matplotlib)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyparsing!=2.0.0,!=2.0.4,>=1.5.6 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyparsing-2.0.6-py2.7.egg (from matplotlib)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg (from python-dateutil->matplotlib)
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.9.1
 Uninstalling numpy-1.9.1:
  Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 246, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 352, in run
      root=options.root_path,
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 687, in install
      requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 730, in uninstall
      paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 126, in remove
      renames(path, new_path)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 292, in renames
      shutil.move(old, new)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 303, in move
      os.unlink(src)
  OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.1.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst'
```

Comment: Check your `which python` path.

Comment: Please show output of `pip list`

Comment: Read the answers to this question: [Pip Install not installing into correct directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607837/pip-install-not-installing-into-correct-directory)

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup matplotlib (1.3.1) is available in pip list

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
I think this is fine

Comment: @k4ppa which python shows the directory is correct.

Comment: `python -m pip install --upgrade matplotlib `

Comment: @PeterWood I used sudo -E pip install matplotlib --upgrade and this is what i got DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (numpy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.

And then 
Uninstalling numpy-1.8.0rc1:
      Exception:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 246, in main
          status = self.run(options, args)

Comment: `brew install matplotlib`

Answer (score 4):

On OS X do not ever install python modules as root, is a quick recipe for never ending failures.

Use the `--user` parameter for `pip` in order to install modules for the current user only, like:

```
localhost:~ sorins$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python

python -m pip install --user --upgrade matplotlib
```

Also, be sure that you are using the correct python interpreters, as it happens often for pip to get confused and to install a module in a location than is not included in the python PATH (sys.path).

Comment: Perfect solution for this problem! Spend more than 1 hour fix this until I finally solved this with you help.