# How to change default install location for python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, scikit-learn

I am using RedHat Linux.
Python 2.6 is already installed in usr/src/bin. When I install Python 2.7, it gets installed in usr/local/src/bin. 
Further, I need to install sklearn. When I try installing sklearn using pip, it refers to Python2.6 and not Python2.7.

Comment: `/usr/local/src/bin/python pip install sklearn`

Answer (score 1):

You can run python -m pip to see if pip is using the right version of python

I think you can probably specify the location with  usr/local/src/bin pip install  If you're sure that's where python 2.7 is installed.  If pip is not using python 2.7 you should reinstall pip in the correct version.

There is another question which could help solve yours: 
[Pip Install not installing into correct directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607837/pip-install-not-installing-into-correct-directory)