# ImportError: No module named 'vaderSentiment'

Tags: python-3.x, vader

[image]

I am installing vaderSentiment via JupiterNotebook and getting the below message
I even tried installing it via commandprompt but I still receive the same error.

Any idea whats going on? I am installing it on GCP linux distribution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try restarting jupyter notebook?

Comment: i restarted the gcp instance, notebook, kernel .. still nothing works

Comment: please make sure that if you installed python3 then check the path.

Comment: this might helpful for you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607837/pip-install-not-installing-into-correct-directory

Comment: Even I faced the same situation once in the past. The problem there is I have multiple versions of python.