# How can I solve ModuleNotFoundError in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, sentiment-analysis, jupyter-lab

Here is my code about sentiment analysis in python so I had a problem on jupyter lab error is no module name but I had everything about the installing part pip install vaderSentiment  and enviroment variable stuff. So What should I do?

```
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
analyser = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

def sentiment_analyzer_scores(sentence):
    score = analyser.polarity_scores(sentence)
    print("{:-<40} {}".format(sentence, str(score)))



 ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-22-f1fda500aee5> in <module>
    ----> 1 from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
          2 analyser = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
          3 
          4 def sentiment_analyzer_scores(sentence):
          5     score = analyser.polarity_scores(sentence)
    
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vaderSentiment'
```

Comment: Did you install that module? If yes, are you sure that you installed it in the correct environment?

Comment: Yes, installing is done "Requirement already satisfied" and my enviroment variables python\Scripts pip path adding but still doesn't work

Comment: This is to few details. You would need to explain your environment in details, providing information on: where is the JupyterLab installed, how you start it, whether you use conda or not, etc. Also, have you tried the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607837/pip-install-not-installing-into-correct-directory?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing its [full master branch zip file](https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment/archive/master.zip) and unzip it in your main file location then either try importing the same way you did or try this other line of code to import it.

```
from vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
```

Also check if you have only one version of python installed and not multiple.

Do try to upgrade pip, python and vaderSentiment to latest versions.

```
pip install --upgrade vaderSentiment
```