# pip missing from bin in virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

`pip` is installing to global location rather than in the venv. I tried a lot of things but none worked. I found out that pip3 is missing from `bin` in my vienv. I have tried all of the below:
[pip installing in global site-packages instead of virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952797/pip-installing-in-global-site-packages-instead-of-virtualenv) and
http://w3facility.org/question/pip-installing-in-global-site-packages-instead-of-virtualenv/
And many more...if you need i can paste more links. Please help.

Comment: Are you using 3.4 or greater?

Comment: can you show us how you set up the virtualenv, activate it and try to run pip from within it?

Answer (score 0):

[Using a virtual environment with Python 3.4](https://robinwinslow.co.uk/2013/12/26/python-3-4-virtual-environment/) provides helpful information about dealing with Python 3.x and virtualenv/pyevn.

Find instruction about how to install pip manually on [pip.pypa.io](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html#install-pip).

Answer (score 0):

The Red Hat yum package of Python 3.4 is broken, with pip missing.  Other Python 3.4+ distributions might have the same problem.

When you create a virtual environment with:

```
pyvenv-3.4 py3
source py3/bin/activate
```

the environment should include pip automatically (in the environment/bin directory, not globally).  If it does not, try downloading the pip and setuptools wheels manually as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/33767179/948866.  It's a little more work up front than installing pip the old way, but it makes pyvenv work properly.