# Pip installing globally and not in virtual environment --- even with all paths and pip pointing to the right place

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv, sudo

I have read [pip installing in global site-packages instead of virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952797/pip-installing-in-global-site-packages-instead-of-virtualenv) and made sure that everything is correct, i even reinstalled pip with easy_install within the virtaulenv.

What happens is strange. First it wont let me install a package without sudo... if I read the text output it tries to place it in the virtualenv path as expected.. I then use sudo and it works.

But if I try to install the package (in this case django-bootstrap3) then it states:

```
(env)kevin@g3:~/djangoP/work$ sudo pip install django-bootstrap3
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django-bootstrap3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
```

which from what I understand means that it is installed outside of the virtualenv.

Not really sure what to do. Have read a few blogs and many people have variations of the issue but I cannot seem to find a solution for myself.

I am using Ubuntu 14, Python 2.7 and working in my home directory.

Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: PS the package cant be found in the site-packages folder hence again I have assume , although it my be assumed in ignorance that the pack is not install, for one django states it cant find the package at all.

Comment: Did you try to run `pip` directly from the virtualenv bin folder?

Answer (score 2):

You should not install packages inside `virtualenv` using `sudo`.

It looks like a file permission problem to me. Either `pip` or `virtualnev` was installed with root privileges ant that is the reason why `sudo` is required when you try to install new packages inside `virtualenv`.

Check file permissions for executables you are using (`virtualenv`, `pip`).

```
dm@Z580:~$ which virtualenv
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
dm@Z580:~$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 214 aug 18 21:20 /usr/local/bin/virtualenv

dm@Z580:~$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
dm@Z580:~$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/pip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 207 jun  3 15:33 /usr/local/bin/pip


dm@Z580:~$ virtualenv -p python2.7 testenv 
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2.7
New python executable in testenv/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in testenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
dm@Z580:~$ source testenv/bin/activate

(testenv)dm@Z580:~$ which pip
/home/dm/testenv/bin/pip
(testenv)dm@Z580:~$ ls -l /home/dm/testenv/bin/pip
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dm dm 219 sep 21 17:29 /home/dm/testenv/bin/pip
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use

```
./bin/pip
```

to install anything in your virtual environment. (I can't comment that's why I had to write here).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today, It turned out that I had set manually `PYTHONPATH` variable in `.bash_profile` file so running in my shell after activating my virtual environment `export PYTHONPATH=`
did the trick for me.