# "python -m venv env" vs "python3 -m venv env"

Tags: python, linux, fedora, python-venv

In Fedora Linux, while creating virtual environment named "env" with,

`python -m venv env`

The virtual environment "env" is populated with global site packages. When I activate the environment and install packages, the packages are being installed as global site packages instead to the virtual environment.

But on using,

`python3 -m venv env`

There are no global site packages, just pip and setuptools are present.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Your system would have multiple versions of python installed. see `python --version` and `python3 --version`

Comment: Could it be that you have two different pythons installed? Check the version when activating the environments

Comment: Both returns the same version number, i.e Python 3.9.7

Comment: try `where python` and `where python3`

Comment: where python and where python3 does not work. I tried "which" instead and got the following. /usr/bin/python and /usr/bin/python3

Comment: maybe this can help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699585/pip-installing-globally-and-not-in-virtual-environment-even-with-all-paths-a