# osx install packages inside virtualenv

Tags: python, macos, pip, virtualenv

I tried to start virtualenv WITHOUT sudo but unfortunately it cannot find (Permission denied) /lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy_install.py. So I did:

```
sudo virtualenv name_env
```

The problem is that now pip is the global version (not inside pip):
which pip:
/usr/local/bin/pip
So I cannot install any package inside the environment.
If I start virtualenv without sudo:

```
virtualenv name_env
```

OSError: Command /Users/andrea/package_lambda/bin/python2.7 -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 2
Any suggestion?

Comment: If any of the answers address your question, please mark it as such so that the thread is closed and the question appears as answered on the board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. I was using iterm instead of terminal (standard mac OS X). Using terminal I did:

```
sudo pip uninstall virtualenv
sudo pip install virtualenv
sudo cp /usr/local/bin/virtualenv /bin/virtualenv
```

Then I can create start a virtualenv:

```
virtualenv name_env
source name_env/bin/activate
```

To install python package on it I use:

```
sudo pip install --target=name_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ package name
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `sudo` just because you can!

I suggest you install another Python environment using `brew`, and then install `pip`, and subsequently `virtualenv`. This way, you'll substantially correct the underlying problem.

I would follow this method:

```
brew install pyenv

pyenv install 2.7.11
```

Or check the available versions through:

```
pyenv versions
```

This way, you can install different versions and switch between them as you wish, for instance:

```
pyenv global 2.7.11
```

And then you can install `pip` like so:

```
python -m easy_intall pip
```

and then install `virtualenv` like so:

```
python -m pip install virtualenv
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However python easy_install -m pip:
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'easy_install': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Apologies. I had a typo in the command. I just corrected it. It is `python -m easy_install pip`, not `python easy_install -m pip`. My bad.

Comment: I got permission denied (because I'm not using sudo):
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-22088.write-test'

Comment: Download Python from python.org and install it. You appear to be having permission issues for some reason.

Comment: I download and installed the last version 2.7.11 Of course it asked my password so I guess it's equivalent to sudo.... I don't get how can you install software in the lib folder without sudo.

Comment: For that yes, it does ask you for the user password. Sudo is not the same as user password.

Comment: Anyway thanks even though the problem is still there. I can write in the lib folder without sudo and I can create a virtualenv without sudo.

Answer (score 0):

As pouria mentioned, I believe it's a good idea to make sure you installed virtualenv using pip in the first place. I also agree that on OSX, using sudo should be rare.

As mentioned on a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952797/pip-installing-in-global-site-packages-instead-of-virtualenv#20954767), you should also check that the files in the bin of your virtual env are correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but yes the path VIRTUAL_ENV is correct and virtualenv has been installed using pip

Answer (score 0):

I have the following file `~/.pydistutils.cfg` with the contents

```
[install]
prefix=
```

temporarily removing this file fixed the issue for me (i had this file in place to address a different issue)