# ImportError: No module named watson_developer_cloud

Tags: python, importerror, ibm-watson

```
## Packages
import sys
import os
import glob
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import watson_developer_cloud

## Cloud service credential connection
discovery_creds = helper.fetch_credentials('discovery')

discovery = watson_developer_cloud.DiscoveryV1(
                        version='2018-08-01',
                        url=discovery_creds['url'],
                        iam_apikey=discovery_creds['apikey'])

## Environment initialization
env, env_id = helper.fetch_object(
    discovery, "environment", "Compugin",
    create=True, create_args=dict(
        description="Compugin 1.0 -- Question/Answering"
    ))

# Lists existing configurations for the service instance and store default configuration id
configurations = discovery.list_configurations(environment_id=env_id).get_result()
cfg_id =  configurations['configurations'][0]['configuration_id']
print(json.dumps(configurations, indent=2))

# List default configuration details
config = discovery.get_configuration(environment_id=env_id, configuration_id=cfg_id).get_result()
print(json.dumps(config, indent=2))

# Test configuration on some sample text
data_dir = "data"
filename = os.path.join(data_dir, "sample.html")
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    res = discovery.test_configuration_in_environment(environment_id=env_id, configuration_id=cfg_id, file=f).get_result()
print(json.dumps(res, indent=2))
```

When trying to run the above python code, I receive this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compugin.py", line 7, in 
    import watson_developer_cloud
ImportError: No module named watson_developer_cloud

I have installed the watson_developer_cloud package using pip, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/441616/importerror-no-module-named-watson-developer-cloud/

Comment: `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: @PedroLobito But if I installed the package manually, do I need to add it to some requirements.txt file? I thought that was just for bulk installs.

Comment: Are you using virtualenv? Also, any IDE like PyCharm?

Comment: @VidyasagarMachupalli I am just running that code directly from my Terminal. Calling: python compugin.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two worlds when we install packages using pip - *Global site-packages and virtualenv packages*

> **Creating Virtual Environments** Python “Virtual Environments” allow Python packages to be installed in an isolated location for a
>   particular application, rather than being installed globally.
>
> Imagine you have an application that needs version 1 of LibFoo, but
>   another application requires version 2. How can you use both these
>   applications? If you install everything into
>   /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (or whatever your platform’s standard
>   location is), it’s easy to end up in a situation where you
>   unintentionally upgrade an application that shouldn’t be upgraded.
>
> Or more generally, what if you want to install an application and
>   leave it be? If an application works, any change in its libraries or
>   the versions of those libraries can break the application.
>
> Also, what if you can’t install packages into the global site-packages
>   directory? For instance, on a shared host.
>
> In all these cases, virtual environments can help you. They have their
>   own installation directories and they don’t share libraries with other
>   virtual environments.
>
> Currently, there are two common tools for creating Python virtual
>   environments:
>
> venv is available by default in Python 3.3 and later, and installs pip
>   and setuptools into created virtual environments in Python 3.4 and
>   later. virtualenv needs to be installed separately, but supports
>   Python 2.7+ and Python 3.3+, and pip, setuptools and wheel are always
>   installed into created virtual environments by default (regardless of
>   Python version).

Read [installing packages](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#creating-virtual-environments)

To under the differences between the global site-packages and virtualenv packages, refer [pip installing in global site-packages instead of virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952797/pip-installing-in-global-site-packages-instead-of-virtualenv)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have not installed yet then run this to install

```
pip install watson_developer_cloud
```