# pip not pointing to virtual enviroment, in virtual enviroment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, virtualenv

I'm using vscode on windows.

have a look here:

```
(ETLAppEnv_3_7) PS C:\Users\jmarshall\source\repos\MediaDesignGroup\ETLApp_Dev> pip show pandas
Name: pandas
Version: 1.0.1
Summary: Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics
Home-page: https://pandas.pydata.org
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: c:\users\jmarshall\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
Requires: pytz, numpy, python-dateutil
Required-by:
```

even though I'm in my virtual environment here:

```
(ETLAppEnv_3_7) PS C:\Users\jmarshall\source\repos\MediaDesignGroup\ETLApp_Dev> pip show pandas
```

pip is working out of the base install of python here:

```
Location: c:\users\jmarshall\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
```

How do I get pip to point to the packages in my virtual environment???

Comment: What tool are you using for your virtual environments?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip installing in global site-packages instead of virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952797/pip-installing-in-global-site-packages-instead-of-virtualenv)

Comment: @AMC virtualenv is the library supporting Visual-Studio-Code.

Comment: _virtualenv is the library supporting Visual-Studio-Code_ What do you mean?

Comment: I'm not sure how VSCode works their integration for virtual environments, but the in the docs [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments), it looks like it supports discovery of venv's created by virtualenv, pyenv, and pipenv.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Duplicate of** [pip installing in global-site packages instead of virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952797/pip-installing-in-global-site-packages-instead-of-virtualenv)

According to that post, the VIRTUAL_ENV path within your venv's activate script might be incorrect.

In my personal experience, I had the *globally-install packages* option selected when I created a venv in PyCharm which resulted in your same issue.

Debug tip: `pip list --local` will give you all the packages installed in you venv. Might want to double check it isn't installed in the venv.

Comment: my VIRTUAL_ENV looks correct:  $env:VIRTUAL_ENV="C:\Users\jmarshall\source\repos\MediaDesignGroup\ETL\ETLApp\ETLAppEnv_3_7"

Comment: Also pip list --local won't work, because 'pip' will always reference the global python installation, not the virtual ENV

Comment: Have you tried using pip3 instead of pip? I have had instances where only pip3 existed.