# Python app install via pip3 does not install source packages

Tags: python

Here is my `python` project structure

```
▶ tree -L 2
.
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── my_app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── utils.py
│   └── views.py
```

And part of my `setup.py`

```
    package_dir={'': 'my_app'},
    packages=find_packages(where='my_app'),
    include_package_data=True,
    python_requires='>=3.9',
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'my-app=my_app.main:run',
        ],
```

```
pip3 install .  --force-reinstall
```

runs OK and I am in a virtualenv.

However, when trying to run the program

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myuser/myfolder/.venv/bin/my-app", line 5, in <module>
    from my_app.main import run
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_app'
```

I also noticed that in `ls .venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/` there are no source files of `my-app`, only `my_app-0.0.1.dist-info` file

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand how `find_packages(where='my_app')` work, see [this](http://code.nabla.net/doc/setuptools/api/setuptools/setuptools.find_packages.html):

> find_packages(where='.', exclude=())
> Return a list all Python packages found within directory 'where'

This means it doesn't mean try to find the package `my_app` from current folder, but try to find packages from the folder `my_app`, in your case, no package will be found in `my_app`.

So, for your case, next is enough:

**setup.py**:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="my-app",
    version="0.0.1",

    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'my-app=my_app.main:run',
        ],
    }
)
```

Additional, if your main intention is just to include `my_app`, bypass others, then `find_packages(include=[` syntax is what you are looking for:

**setup.py**:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="my-app",
    version="0.0.1",

    packages=find_packages(include=['my_app']),
    include_package_data=True,
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'my-app=my_app.main:run',
        ],
    }
)
```

**NOTE**, don't use `package_dir={'': 'my_app'}`, it will try to find `my_app.my_app`, unless you use `package_dir={'my_app': 'my_app'}`, but it's meaningless in your case.

Answer (score 0):

is not it the solution?
[pip installing in global site-packages instead of virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952797/pip-installing-in-global-site-packages-instead-of-virtualenv)
I had smth similar on worked machine, requirements satisfied on installing, but module not found on run, removed that package globally and installed again. Might will help