# ImportError: No module named click

Tags: python, click

I'm attempting to use click within a Python 3 virtualenv (3.9.5) script and I keep getting an import error even after installing it via pip. When I attempt to install it again it says requirement already satisfied. I feel like I'm missing something simple.

[image]

Comment: Try uninstalling it and installing it again. Also make sure that your site-packages file in Python39 is going through your system path.

Comment: pip seems to be not be installing to the virtualenv, and it is installing to the system packages. Try recreating your venv, or look at https://serverfault.com/questions/526594/pip-not-installing-to-virtualenv-directory.

Comment: Ensure that `pip` that is being executed is in fact from the current virtualenv by running `which pip`, you may find that it is not in fact inside the `click` venv.  To be sure that you are running the same `pip` with the currently activated `python`, run `python -m pip` instead.  Since you are on OS X, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952797/pip-installing-in-global-site-packages-instead-of-virtualenv/20954767) may be rather relevant.

Comment: @KetZoomer it looks like it is not installing inside of the virtualenv like you said. I attempted to recreate the virtualenv and I'm running into the same thing. I took a look at the article you posted and I saw step 3 "To get pip working, you must correct the python interpreter in the pip file, this as well has a static interpreter location set by virtualenv in the creation process." but no steps on how to do that.

Comment: It may be useful to check the output of `which pip` and `which python`, and provide that output with your question.

Answer (score 1):

Although you are using virutalenv but just in case, make sure you are using the same version of python where click is installed, to run your script.
try to do a `pip freeze` or `pip list` to check all the modules installed, do it with and without the virtualenv activated. sometimes a simple restart of the cmd prompt can solve the issue. These kinds of problems are common in windows

Answer (score -1):

Not sure but I think you should try again by changing name of virtual envirment. Because you have used same name for virtual envirment.