# Installing python packages in a VSCode virtual environment isn't working (requirement already satisfied)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, virtualenv

So I have a virtual environment set up in VS Code. I recently learned that it's better this way because it doesn't interfere with my global python data. The problem is that I'm still getting issues. When I try to install a package in that environment using pip, it gives a message like this and it doesn't install:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: {PACKAGE NAME} in c:\users\lavaa\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages
```

I activated the environment and selected it as my interpreter before this.

This confuses me because why should it care about that python directory when I'm in a virtual environment? It's not already installed in the virtual environment, so there should be no problem, right? I didn't want to mess anything up, so here I am.

One last thing: When I went to the appdata directory to find the issue, I saw that the package was installed there. I don't know why it didn't get placed in the virtual environment folder.

Comment: I found a post that might describe my situation better:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952797/pip-installing-in-global-site-packages-instead-of-virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

If you use `pip` command to install, the package will be installed in pyenv.

If you are using conda environment you can use the following command to install:

```
conda install packageName
```

You can read [document about environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) for more information.