# pip install -r requirements.txt is not working in venv

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

i have this weird problem with python venvs. If i activate the venv and try to install packages via `pip install -r requirements.txt` the packages are getting installed to the global python and not in the venv.

i am using python 3.11.2 on Debian Bookworm.

I've googled now 2 hours and tried everything including everything in [pip installing in global site-packages instead of virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952797/pip-installing-in-global-site-packages-instead-of-virtualenv) and nothing helped. The path are correctly set,`which pip` gives me the path to the venv pip, there are no aliases, i created configfiles but nothing helped.

Then i tried to install a package without the -r requirements.txt e.g. `pip install numpy` that worked and the packages were installed inside the venv.
So what's the problem of pip not installing packages with the -r parameter to the venv?

Comment: Can you post the contents of the requirements.txt?

Comment: Do this first `pip freeze > requirements.txt`  then do this second `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: I don't used ven. here is link: https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pip-list-freeze/

Comment: @toyotaSupra, if you do `pip freeze > requirements.txt` in the root of the source directory, then it will overwrite the requirements.txt of the source with the current `pip freeze` result . Because of `>`. But OP wants to install the requirements.txt of the source.

Comment: @spo The content of the requirements.txt is:
`--extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118 numpy==1.23.5
etc.`

Comment: Please post the full content in your question.

Comment: What does `which pip` output? Are you sure you running the `pip` installed in the virtual environment? (If you are sure `python` is the correct interpreter, you can also use `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt` to install into the venv.)

Comment: after activating your env do `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: You need to include exact and complete steps to replicate your scenario. Enough that *anyone* could follow them and be *guaranteed* to get the same error. (Added to the question, not as comments.) [mre]

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I think you error is occurring because pip is still referring to the global pip. This command refers to python's (the venv python) pip instead of the global python's pip.

Comment: may be pip is not installed in virtualenv. try `python -m ensurepip` to install `pip` in virtualenv.

Comment: No, my pip is referring to the pip in the venv. I've run `which pip` and it gave me the path to the venv. I also referred via absolute path to the venv pip - which gave me the same result

Comment: Still only ever use `python -m` inside venv. It's one of those golden rules that avoids a million subtle problems like this.